# UITextView does not change textColor property

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uitextview

I have a UITextView custom class:

```
class TitleTextView: UITextView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textColor = .brand100
        backgroundColor = .clear
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        textAlignment = .left
        isScrollEnabled = false
        let frameWidth = Constants.screenSize.width * 87.5 / 100
        font = UIFont.OpenSans(.semibold, size: (frameWidth * 8.55 / 100))
    }
 }
```

I used this text view custom class inner a UIView.

```
class MyCustomHeaderView: UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextView: TitleTextView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        backgroundColor = .brand100

        titleTextView.text = "Market Place"
        titleTextView.textColor = .brand400

        layoutIfNeeded()

    }    

}
```

And I called this UIView in a UIViewController.

```
private func setupTitleView() {
        let titleView = UINib(nibName: "TitleView", bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! UIView
        titleView.frame = contentHeaderView.bounds
        contentHeaderView.addSubview(titleView)        
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

But when I set the textColor property in my custom UIView (MyCustomHeaderView) the color doesn't change.

Do you have any idea about why the reason that my UITextView doesn't apply the color that I set in my custom UIView?
 
I called `layoutIfNeed()` but this doesn't work.

Comment: I think in this line ```        let titleView = UINib(nibName: "TitleView", bundle: .main).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as! UIView ``` you should change the type from UIView to the custom class you need

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are doing everything inside the `layoutSubviews` Which in itself is really bad practice.

In your case you instantiate the `CustomHeaderView` and the layout for that is called, hence calling `layoutSubviews` next step is that the `textView` is added to your `CustomHeaderView` and then the textView's `layoutSubviews` is called and will override your color.

You can solve this in two ways i believe. Altho i don't work with Nibs and storyboards,

first:

```
class MyCustomHeaderView: UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextView: TitleTextView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        backgroundColor = .brand100

        titleTextView.text = "Market Place"
        titleTextView.textColor = .brand400

        layoutIfNeeded()

    }    

}
```

Second, this is a big maybe:

```
class MyCustomHeaderView: UIView{

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextView: TitleTextView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        defer {
            backgroundColor = .brand100

            titleTextView.text = "Market Place"
            titleTextView.textColor = .brand400

            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }    

}
```

Defer will wait till everything is been initialised before running whatever is in the block. I don't know tho how that works with layoutSubviews